# rspec test to check if #new called on class

Tags: rspec

I'm trying to write a test for the following method when the if condition is met (create an instance of DispatchMessenger).

```
class Telephony
  def self.receive(body, opts = {})

    responder = Responder.find_by_phone(opts[:from])

    if responder
      msg = DispatchMessenger.new(responder)
    else
      send("#{opts[:from]}: #{opts[:body]}", to: Rails.configuration.backup_sms_phone)
    end

  end
end
```

In rspec I have this.

```
describe '#receive' do

  let(:responder)      { create(:user, :responder, phone: '666-555-4444', name: 'Roy the Responder') }

  it "creates an instance of DispatchMessenger when passed a responder's number" do
    expect(DispatchMessenger).to receive(:new).with(responder)
    Telephony.receive('Body', from: '666-555-4444', body: 'Testing')
  end
end
```

When I run the test I receive this error message.

```
1) Telephony#receive creates an instance of DispatchMessenger when passed a responder's number
 Failure/Error: expect(DispatchMessenger).to receive(:new).with(responder)
   (<DispatchMessenger (class)>).new(#<User id: 16757, email: "roy.the.responder@gmail.com", name: "Roy the Responder", phone: "6665554444", role: "responder", active: true, long: nil, lat: nil>)
       expected: 1 time with arguments: (#<User id: 16757, email: "roy.the.responder@gmail.com", name: "Roy the Responder", phone: "6665554444", role: "responder", active: true, long: nil, lat: nil>)
       received: 0 times with arguments: (#<User id: 16757, email: "roy.the.responder@gmail.com", name: "Roy the Responder", phone: "6665554444", role: "responder", active: true, long: nil, lat: nil>)
```

I want this test to simply confirm that an instance of DispatchMessenger is created if this particular phone number is passed to Telephony#receive. Is this comparing objects to each other where I should instead be comparing a specific attribute(i.e. phone number)? If so, how can I do that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, objects are not `==` and you should be comparing attributes with [have_attributes](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/have-attributes-matcher) matcher.

```
let(:responder) { have_attributes(phone: '666-555-4444', name: 'Roy the Responder') }
```

For attributes with no value you can use [respond_to](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/built-in-matchers/respond-to-matcher) matcher.