# RSpec: How to test whether :new is called on a class double

Tags: rspec

I'd like to test whether `:new` is called on a class when a certain line of code is run. I have the following:

```
class TravelCard
  def check_in(station)
    self.in_journey = true
    self.current_journey = Journey.new(station)
  end
end
```

Using a double, I want to test that the `Journey` class receives the `:new` message when `card.check_in` is run, but I can't get class doubles to do this. If I try the following in RSpec

```
describe TravelCard do
  describe '#check_in' do    
    it 'creates a new journey' do
      journey = class_double("Journey")
      station = double(:station)
      expect(journey).to receive(:new).with(:station)
      card.check_in(station)
    end
  end
end
```

I get

```
 Failure/Error: expect(journey).to receive(:initialize).with(:station)

       (ClassDouble(Journey) (anonymous)).initialize(:station)
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (:station)
           received: 0 times
```

Can anyone explain what this reference to `anonymous` is, and more importantly, how to successfully test whether `:new` is called on a class double using RSpec?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012396/rspec-test-to-check-if-new-called-on-class), but the asker's own problem was solved without testing whether `:new` had been called on a class.

Comment: Just to make sure -- in your test you're calling `#touch_in` instead `#check_in`, is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, good spot. I was actually calling #check_in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `station` instance instead of a symbol.

So try to remove the ":"

`expect(journey).to receive(:new).with(station)`

Also, add the `.as_stubbed_const` after your `class_double` call.

`journey = class_double("Journey").as_stubbed_const`